# Clicking p:commandButton causes the value of p:selectOneMenu being set twice

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, commandbutton

I ran into an issue with PrimeFaces - consider form with `SelectOneMenu` being put inside of `Inplace`. Next to the Inplace we have a `CommandButton` that is meant to reset the value of the `SelectOneMenu`.

The form looks like this:

```xml
<h:form id="myform">
    <p:inplace id="inplace" editor="true">
        <p:ajax event="save" update="@(form)" />

        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{testBean.year}" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="selYears" value="#{testBean.year}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="2015" itemLabel="2015" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="2014" itemLabel="2014" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="2013" itemLabel="2013" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:inplace>

    <p:commandButton id="btnResetYear" value="Reset year" rendered="#{testBean.year lt 2015}"
        action="#{testBean.resetYear()}" update="@(form)" />

</h:form>
```

This is the TestBean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {
    private int year;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.year = 2015;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        System.out.println("---> setYear: " + year);
        this.year = year;
        this.someMethod();
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("---> someMethod: " + this.year);
    }

    public void resetYear() {
        System.out.println("---> resetYear");
        this.setYear(2015);
    }
}
```

The following scenario works just fine:

1. Click the year to show the actual `SelectOneMenu`
2. Select different year (e.g. 2013)
3. Confirm the selection by clicking the "check" button

However, if I try clicking the "Reset year" button, the method `setYear` is called with the original year as a parameter just before `resetYear` is called. This is what I can see in a console:

```
12:28:40,003 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ---> setYear: 2013
12:28:40,003 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ---> someMethod: 2013
12:28:40,004 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ---> resetYear
12:28:40,004 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ---> setYear: 2015
12:28:40,004 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ---> someMethod: 2015
```

Which is what I do not want as `someMethod` is intended to e.g. load data from DB and there is no reason to run it for the original value and then for the new value again.

If I use the standard `CommandButton` instead of the one provided by PrimeFaces, it seems to work properly:

```xml
<h:commandButton id="btnResetYear" value="Reset year" rendered="#{testBean.year lt 2015}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{testBean.resetYear}" render="myform" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Clicking the standard button would give the expected result:

```
12:42:11,506 INFO  [stdout] (default task-88) ---> resetYear
12:42:11,506 INFO  [stdout] (default task-88) ---> setYear: 2015
12:42:11,506 INFO  [stdout] (default task-88) ---> someMethod: 2015
```

**QUESTION:**

Is this a bug in PrimeFaces or did I do anything wrong? Is there a way to setup the PF's CommandButton to behave like described above, i.e. not to trigger the `setYear` method with old parameter passed in or do I have to stick with the "standard" `CommandButton`?

I was experimenting with setting `immediate="true"` to the `CommandButton` and it indeed skipped setting the original value first, but the `SelectOneMenu` didn't take the new value into account, no matter what I put into the button's `update` attribute - it was still showing the original value.

The example was run using the following:

- Java 1.8 (jdk1.8.0_51 - 64bit)
- PrimeFaces 5.2
- WildFly 8.2.0 (also tested with JBoss 7.1)

Any idea is more than welcome.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few more hours I figured out what the problem was - the default behavior of PF's `CommandButton` is to process everything on the page, which is basically the same as if I set `process="@all"`

I found out this by checking details of the request/response sent/received by the `CommandButton` - there was the following parameter in the request header:

```
javax.faces.partial.execute = @all
```

So setting `process="@this"` to the `CommandButton` did the trick and I can observe the correct behavior now:

```
18:45:51,874 INFO  [stdout] (default task-41) ---> resetYear
18:45:51,874 INFO  [stdout] (default task-41) ---> setYear: 2015
18:45:51,874 INFO  [stdout] (default task-41) ---> someMethod: 2015
```

This is the final version of my `CommandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnResetYear" value="Reset year" rendered="#{testBean.year lt 2015}"
    action="#{testBean.resetYear()}" update="@(form)" process="@this" />
```

I hope to save someone else's time by posting this solution here :-)